# Spring Mongo DB @DBREF

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mongo, spring-mongodb

I am having trouble writing code that would allow get a user and claim details in a straightforward way. This is my MongoDB structure,

```
db.user.find();
```

```
user: 
    {
    "name" : "KSK", 
     "claim"  : [objectId("52ffc4a5d85242602e000000"),objectId("52ffc4a5d85242602e000001")] 
    }

claim: 

    [
       {
         "_id" : "52ffc4a5d85242602e000001",
         "claimName" :"XXXX"
       },
       {
         "_id" : "52ffc4a5d85242602e000000",
         "claimName" :"YYY"
       }
    ]
```

My Entity class is:

```
@Document(collection="user")
public  class User{
    @Id      
    private String id;
    private String name; 
    @DBRef
    private List<Claim> claim; 
    // setter and getter   
}
```

Claim Class:

```java
@Document(collection="Claim")
public class Claim{
    @Id 
    private String id; 
    private String claimName;   
}
```

I have a  method to get the users by name like below,

```java
public User findByName(String name);
```

If I try to hit this method am getting an error that,

No converter found capable of converting from type `org.bson.types.ObjectId` to type `java.lang.String`

So I changed my User entity class as like below,

Instead of  `private List<Claim> claim`;

Changed as `Private List<ObjectId> claim`;

Now if I execute a method(findByName), I get a user object that has both claimed object ids `("52ffc4a5d85242602e000001","52ffc4a5d85242602e000000")`, then iterate the claim list and get the claim details corresponding to the claim object Id.

Instead of doing this, when I execute `findByName` method I want to get a user and claim details. How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: Your initial approach with List<Claim> looks alright. Are you sure it isn't a camel case issue, see ``claimname`` in your Java class and ``claimName`` in your JSON.

Comment: @Matt it just a typo error. I modified now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you reference your `Claim`s in the `User` class with @DBRef, your JSON should not only contain the ID but the reference to the collection where to find the ID as well, like this:

```
{
  "name" : "KSK", 
  "claim" : [ 
     { 
       "$ref" : "claim", // the target collection
       "$id" : ObjectId("52ffc4a5d85242602e000000")
     }
  ] 
}
```

That is how Spring-Data maps your Java objects to **MongoDB**. If you start with a blank database and let Spring create and save the relations, you should have no problems using

```
 @DBRef List<Claim> claims;
```

Comment: how can i get the user_id of the claim ?

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is not to set that Claim class into separate @Document or just switch back to Relational Databases, because it's not a Mongo approach.
Also, if you insist on current architecture you can try using @DBRef above that List in User.class into smth like this:

```
public class ParentModel {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private ParentType parentType;

    private SubType subType;

    @DBRef
    private List<Model> models;

....
}
```

Comment: I missed out to add DBRef in my post. Now I have edited it. Please look at now.  As you suggested if I go with  embedded relationship, if the embedded document keeps on growing too much in size, it can impact the read/write performance. That's why I decided to go with reference relationship.

Comment: you will exceed 16 mb? That should be a huge document. If you managed to get User with List<Claim> i do not really understand what you want above this? Mb if you explain it more clearly I will try to help

Comment: If I add DBRef  private List<Claim>I am getting an error. I have mentioned the error in my post. What I need is, when I call a findByName then I want a user and corresponding to the claims details.

Comment: did you generate getters and setters?you can use Lombok for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative to @DBRef, take a look at RelMongo ([link](https://kaiso.github.io/relmongo/))
which provides a powerfull way to manage relations, in your case it will be like this :

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private list<Claim> claims;
```